# accepting data on mvc controller passed from js function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have razor view which takes some ul list items which process further into js function. Those ul list items are used to store into object array which 
will be sent over the wire to the mvc controller. This object is casted to my model as parameter on mvc controller.

```
public class MyModel
{
    ....
    public List<Prize> Prizes { get; set; }
}


public class Prize
{
    public int Name {get; set;}
    public int LastName {get; set;}
    public int Age {get; set;}  
}
```

on controller side

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(MyModel dataToEdit)
{
    data.ToEdit other properties are populated correctly
    ...
    ... dataToEdit.Prizes are empty
});
```

script inside view

```
function editGame() {
    var items = $("#myValues > ul > li");            
    var prizeArr = [];
    items.each(function () {                
        prizeArr.push({ Name:"test", LastName: "5", Age: "8" });
    });

    var myObj = {
         someData: $('#someCombo').val().toString(),              
         Prizes: prizeArr
     };

     $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         traditional: true,
         contentType: 'application/json',
         url: '/MyController/Edit',
         data: JSON.stringify({ dataToEdit: myObj }),
         success: function () {
             alert("complete");
         }
     });
};
```

How can I successfully receive Prizes in the MVC controller? Right now using this code Prizes list is empty, even though I'm sending non empty array (prizeArr).

update:
tried with

```
 data: { dataToEdit: myObj },
 traditional: true,
```

but still doesn't work.

Comment: What is succ. receive?

Comment: Try giving jQuery the plain object in the data property: `data: { dataToEdit: myObj }` and then set `traditional: true`. This modifies the way the data is serialised which may help the default ModelBinder.

Comment: Or else just try like this - `var dataToEdit={
                someData: $('#someCombo').val().toString(),              
                Prizes: prizeArr
            };` and in data of ajax just pass dataToEdit as `JSON.stringify(dataToEdit)`

Comment: I have tested your code as shown (and except for removing the parenthesis in the class definition - `public class MyModel { ...}`) it works fine. The collection is bound with a `Prize` object

Comment: You actually getting dataToEdit.Prizes as non empty collection as parameter in mvc controller action?

Comment: @user1765862, Yes, Its all binding fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried the following and it works, the Prizes bind just find.

```
var prizeArr = [];
for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
{
    prizeArr.push({ Name:"test", LastName: "5", Age: "8" });
}

var myObj = {
     SomeData: "This is a value",              
     Prizes: prizeArr
 };

 $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     traditional: true,
     contentType: 'application/json',
     url: '/BindingTest/Index',
     data: JSON.stringify({myModel: myObj}),
     success: function () {
         alert("complete");
     }
 });
```

I stripped out your line `var items = $("#myValues > ul > li");` and replaced the `.each` with a simple `for` loop.

I suggest that your items jQuery select isn't returning any selected tags, thus the each isn't looping at all so the prizes aren't being added.

Use the Chrome `F12` menu under the `Network` tab to check that some data is being submitted in the post.

[image: Inspect to see the posted data]

If it isn't shown in the window, then it won't be posted to the controller action and bound to your model.

Comment: Not necessary when using `traditional: true`. And in any case, if using indexers the values would need to be `Prizes[i].Name: 'test', Prizes[i].LastName: '5',` etc